# Dockerfile RUN powershell wget and see progress

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-for-windows, powershell-cmdlet

In my dockerfile want to use the following sequence of commands to download and extract a large zip file:

```
RUN powershell -Command                           \
    wget http://my_server/big_huge.zip            \
        -OutFile C:\big_huge.zip ;                \
    Expand-Archive -Path C:\big_huge.zip          \
                   -DestinationPath C:\big_huge ; \
    Remove-Item C:\big_huge.zip -Force
```

I don't want to use ADD to download the zip file isn't going to change and I want this step to be cached.

What I have above seems to work but I do not get any indication of the progress of the download like I normally would. That's a bummer because this is a large download. The progress of the download is obscured I suppose because `Invoke-WebRequest` which `wget` is an alias to is a cmdlet. Is there any way to pipe the output of a cmdlet to stdout so I can see it when I am running `docker build`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on trying to do the download from the Dockerfile and instead wrote a separate script that pre-downloads the files I need and expands their archives if the files aren't already present. This script then calls `docker build`, `docker run`, etc. In the Dockerfile I am copying the directory where I expanded the archives.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Docker. But maybe you can pipe the output through the powershell cmdlet **Out-Host**. Type in **help Out-Host** for more information.

Comment: Piping the output to Out-Host doesn't change how this command performs on my host system, and it just fails when I try to use it in the docker file. `'Out-Host' is not recognized a an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Ok. I am using the Powershell Core version 7. Out-Host maybe not the solution for you but it is strange that you don't have it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host